# PHPmyadmin wordpress comments count query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

```
UPDATE mydomain.1we9ZZc0_posts wpp
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT comment_post_id AS c_post_id, count(*) AS cnt FROM mydomain.1we9ZZc0_comments
WHERE comment_approved = 1 GROUP BY comment_post_id) wpc
ON wpp.id=wpc.c_post_id
SET wpp.comment_count=wpc.cnt
WHERE wpp.post_type IN ('post', 'page')
AND (wpp.comment_count!=wpc.cnt OR (wpp.comment_count != 0 AND wpc.cnt IS NULL));
```

That query is supposed to correct a list of false comment counts on my site but I am getting this error....

```
UPDATE mydomain.1we9ZZc0_posts wppLEFT JOIN(SELECT comment_post_id AS c_post_id, count(*) AS cnt FROM mydomain.1we9ZZc0_commentsWHERE comment_approved = 1 GROUP BY comment_post_id) wpcON wpp.id=wpc.c_post_idSET wpp.comment_count=wpc.cntWHERE wpp.post_type IN ('post', 'page')AND (wpp.comment_count!=wpc.cnt OR (wpp.comment_count != 0 AND wpc.cnt IS NULL));
```

MySQL said:

> #1048 - Column 'comment_count' cannot be null

See above. I tried that query but I got it from a 5 year old thread so the "cannot be null" must be something having to do with the age of the query.

Comment: from error message I can see that wpc.cnt is null for condition wpp.id=wpc.c_post_id. You can  use ISNULL( wpc.cnt, 0), so that if value is null 0 should be updated as wpp.comment_count is not nullable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am having issues getting this to work without errors. Can you please reply with the modified code in it's entirety? I appreciate your help greatly.